# Как уничтожить объект JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. 
Возможно ли уничтожить объект `JavaScript` и освободить память? Если да, то КАК?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в этом действительно будет необходимость и это не повредит целостности кода - сборщик мусора сделает все за вас.

В противном случае - скорее всего это бесполезная трата времени ( поверьте javascript сейчас оптимизирован достаточно чтобы достойно справляться с подобной задачей )

---

А после чего у вас вообще появились такие мысли? Если какой-то код недостаточно быстро работает или ест много памяти - скорее всего виноват код, а не какой-то объект

---

Для того чтобы переменная имела значение неопределенности, достаточно ей (как ни странно :D) присвоить неопределенность, т.е. например:

```
var someObj = {someValue1: 0, someValue2: 1};
console.log(someObj);  // -> { someValue1: 0, someValue2: 1 }
someObj = undefined;
console.log(someObj)   // -> undefined, теперь (someObj === undefined) === true
// но, надо знать и понимать, что
undefined != false     // -> true
```

---

Чтобы можно было использовать условие типа `if(!someObj)`, достаточно

```
  someObj = false; // теперь - !someObj === true
```

Comment: Мне надо делать переменную типа "undefined"

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить - зачем?

Comment: Ну, по логике приложения, должно красивее выйти. Такая ситуация:  
Есть некоторый объект. После его использования, он "деактивируется". Затем, когда надо будет снова этим объектом пользоваться, его надо создавать заново. Чем создавать какие-то флаги, обозначающие надобность создавать его заново хочется просто сделать так:  
 `
    if(!this.myObj)
        this.myObj = new ........
`

Answer (score 3):

**Судя по вашей цели,** вы можете просто написать `myObject = null`. Это автоматически уменьшает количество ссылок на объект *(т.е, если больше ссылок нет, то в ближайшем будущем он будет освобожден сборщиком мусора).*

Соответственно, для поддержки вашей логики вы можете использовать конструкцию типа `if (myObject == null) ...`

Answer (score 1):

Напрямую - нельзя...

Можно вручную убрать все ссылки на него, и через некоторое время сборщик мусора его сам удалит)

Comment: Импорты являются ссылками?
Что является ссылками?

Answer (score 0):

[delete](http://javascript.ru/delete) obj; - вы это имеете в виду?

Comment: Это удаление ссылки и свойства, а не объекта

Comment: Ну почему же?  

    var o = {abc: 1};console.log(o);delete o;console.log(o);

Comment: Удалить переменную - невозможно...